# Removing FMOD from a Unity WebGL project causes an error about not being able to copy fmod_register_static_plugins.cpp

Tags: unity, webgl, fmod

When I imported the FMOD plugin into a Unity WebGL project, then removed it afterwards, I wasn't able to build it due to errors about trying to copy an FMOD file: fmod_register_static_plugins.cpp

Restarting the editor, reimporting everything, deleting Library/Temp folders did not help. Neither did deleting the FMod folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AstroGrep, I was able to find that ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset was still referencing the file. Search for either "fmod_register_static_plugins.cpp" or "additionalIl2CppArgs", and delete the references to the offending files. Building the project again worked.